# How use input and output file in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, input, output

I have a Python script that inputs all words from a file and sorts them in order:

```
with open(raw_input("Enter a file name: ")) as f :
     for t in sorted(i for line in f for i in line.split()):
           print t
```

But instead of asking every time for the input file I would like to choose the input file with a "-i" and save the output file with a "-o", this way:

```
python myscript.py -i input_file.txt -o output_file.txt
```

and BTW, how to save the output on a target file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', dest='infile',
                    help="input file", metavar='INPUT_FILE')
parser.add_argument('-o', dest='outfile',
                    help='output file', metavar='OUTPUT_FILE')
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.infile, 'r') as infile:
    indata = infile.read()

words = indata.split()
words.sort()

with open(args.outfile, 'w') as outfile:
    for word in words:
        outfile.write('{}\n'.format(word))
```

[`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) is a built-in module for parsing command-line options. It does all the work for you.

```
$ ./SO_32030424.py --help
usage: SO_32030424.py [-h] [-i INPUT_FILE] [-o OUTPUT_FILE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
  -i INPUT_FILE   input file
  -o OUTPUT_FILE  output file
```

Comment: All good, but it gives me an error: I do think that in this way is not creating a file:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 15, in <module>
    with open(args.outfile) as outfile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dest.txt'

Comment: Whoops! I didn't specify the mode; fixed.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to add 'w' but it didn't worked. What else have you changed? I want to learn.

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani, that's all I changed. Can you paste your code that didn't work even with `'w'` on a pastebin?

Comment: too late. Probably it was caused by no come before 'w'

Comment: may I use a ": continue" if the word is already in list or do I have to create a "list()"?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani, you don't want to write duplicates?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87133/discussion-between-francesco-mantovani-and-cyphase).

Answer (score 0):

To get started on your parameters, take a look at `sys.argv`.

To write into an output file, use the write mode "w", and `.write()` to it.

For the latter there are definitely good tutorials out there.

Comment: `sys.argv` takes only bare parameters as a list but did not deal with flags like `-i`.

Comment: Yeah, you can write that yourself though. Or use argparse.